# Can't Attatch 5mb csv file using php

Tags: php

Hi Guys I'm currently creating a script that would automatically attach the csv file and automatically send to the client. i can attach a csv file size 500kb below but when i will attach a 5mb csv file. This error will display

Error sending email: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Rejected - Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size. Size: 6549 KB, Max size: 1000 KB SMTP code: 554Message not Sent! Email

```
 $mailto = 'sample@gmail.com';
            $subject = "REPORT";
            $email_message = "<div>Monthly Report....</div> ";


                  $mail = new PHPMailer;

                  $mail->isSMTP();  
                  $mail->IsHTML(true);                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
                  $mail->Host = 'sample.com.ph';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                  $mail->Username = 'sample';                 // SMTP username
                  $mail->Password = 'sample';                           // SMTP password

                  $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
                  $mail->From = 'sample@sample.ph';
                  $mail->FromName = 'sample';
                  $mail->addAddress($mailto);     // CLIENT 
                  $mail->allowedFiles = array( 'php','doc','csv','xls','zip' );
                  $mail->maxSize = 70000000;   
                  $mail->message_size_limit = 1000000000000000;
                  $mail->SetFrom('info@companyname.com', 'new application submitted');
                  $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
                  $mail->Subject = "your subject";
                  $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
                  $mail->MsgHTML($email_message);
                  $address = 'info@companyname.com';
                  $mail->AddAddress($address, "companyname");

                  $set_path= $path.'/'.$filename;
                  $mail->AddAttachment($set_path, $filename, 'base64', 'text/csv');



            if (!$mail->Send()) {
              /* Error */
              echo "Error sending email: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;  
              echo 'Message not Sent! Email';
            } else {
              /* Success */
              echo 'Sent Successfully! <b> Check your Mail</b>';
            }
```

========================================================================

Comment: what error? you mean what you echo when `$mail->Send()` is false? what's outputted from `$mail->ErrorInfo`?

Comment: Error sending email: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Rejected - Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size. Size: 6549 KB, Max size: 1000 KB SMTP code: 554Message not Sent! Email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error says your email server rejected the message.  This isn't likely something you're going to be able to solve with PHP.

You could try compressing the csv file or address the maximum email size limit defined on the account on your email server.

Answer (score 0):

**Header did you got the error**

```
Rejected - Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size. Size: 6549 KB, Max size: 1000 KB SMTP code: 554Message not Sent! Email
```

it says that your default & max size is only 1000kb and your message was 6549kb how it possible to send this mail.

**Solution** you need to edit file max size maybe it helpful.

Comment: upload_max_filesize 80000M 
post_max_size  900000M 
i already edit this and noting happens